# Angular NGRx Pagination

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

i am working on a table that paginates list of staff on angular with Ngrx for managing the states but when i paginate i could get it work to fetch the data from the store in stead of sending request to the server for every revisited page.

here is my code

on staff.effect.ts

```
export const loadStaffs = createEffect(
  (
    actions$ = inject(Actions),
    staffService = inject(StaffService),
    store = inject(Store<IStaff>)
  ) => {
    return actions$.pipe(
      ofType(StaffActions.loadNewStaff),
      withLatestFrom(store.select(selectPagination)),
      exhaustMap(([action, staffs]) => {
     

          return staffService.getAll(action.params).pipe(
            map((staffsList) =>
              StaffActions.loadStaffSuccess({ staffs: staffsList })
            ),
            catchError((error: { message: string }) =>
              of(StaffActions.loadStaffFailure({ errorMsg: error.message }))
            )
          );

        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  },
  { functional: true }
);
```

the reducer

```
 on(StaffActions.loadStaffSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return staffAdapter.setAll(action.staffs.result, {
      ...state,
      pagination: action.staffs.pagination,

    });
  }),
```

the component

```
 constructor(
    private store: Store<AppStateModel>,
    private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private staffService: StaffService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.params = this.staffService.getParams();
    console.log(this.params);
    this.store.dispatch(StaffActions.loadNewStaff({params: this.params}));

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.params = { ...this.params, ...params };
      console.log(this.params);
      this.fetchData(this.params);
    });

  }

  fetchData(params: Params){
    console.log(this.params);
    this.staffService.setParams(this.params);
    console.log(this.params);
    this.store.dispatch(StaffActions.loadNewStaff({params: this.params}));
    this.staffs$ = this.store.select(getStaffList);

    this.store.select(selectPagination).subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataSource.data = Object.values(data.entities);
      this.pagination = data.pagination;
      console.log(data);
      this.sortDataSource(); // Sort the data source after it is updated
    });
    const currentUserString = localStorage.getItem('userData');
    this.currentUser = currentUserString ? JSON.parse(currentUserString) : null;
    console.log(this.currentUser);
    if (this.currentUser) {
      this.sortDataSource(); // Sort the data source if there is a current user
    }
  }  



handlePageEvent(event: PageEvent) {
    this.pageEvent = event;

    // Update the params object with the new page number and page size values
    this.params = {
      ...this.params,
      pageNumber: event.pageIndex + 1,
      pageSize: event.pageSize
    };

    // Dispatch an action to load the new page data with the updated params
    this.store.dispatch(StaffActions.loadNewStaff({ params: this.params }));

    // Update the query parameters in the URL
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: this.params,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
      preserveFragment: true
    });

  }
```

the HTML

```
   <mat-paginator [length]="pagination.TotalCount"
               [pageSize]="pagination.PageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50]"
               [pageIndex]="pagination.CurrentPage -1"
               [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
               (page)="handlePageEvent($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```